# React-Native : calculating the scrollToItem of a FlatList with a ref on componentDidMount and rendering it

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList which renders numbers from 1-10 along with a radio button. If I have pre-selected number which could be dynamic, that numbered radio button is pre-selected. How to calculate the scrollToItem/scrollToIndex in this case ?

```
componentDidMount() {
     this.scrollToItem();
}

 scrollToItem = () => {
    let dynamicIndex = dynamicIndex 
  //calcuate the dynamic Index

   this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: dynamicIndex });

};

 <FlatList
    ref={ref => {this.flatListRef = ref;}}
    bounces={false}
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    data={listData}
    renderItem={({ item, index })=>
       this.renderItem(item,index)}
   />
```

But it throws error "Cannot read property 'scrollToIndex' of index. Basically it can't find 'this.flatListRef' during component mount.

Comment: it doesn't look like you defined `flatListRef` anywhere.  Just add `flatListRef:any;` above the `componentDidMount` method.